# Issue Installing .apk file

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have a problem while I'm installing my app. I had made an process that checks if exists the new version of the app. My app is private so I uploaded the .apk file to my private server. And when I download the app and I install it at the end shows me an error "Application not installed". Anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: did you signed the application?

Comment: ..with the same key? Increased the versioncode?

Comment: Yes, with the same key and increasing the version code.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall previously installed app version